# Local-storage backbone models

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I am trying to use, https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage, to store models. I ve got a JSON and I am fetch data with backbone and I am trying to local store the fetched data. The first variable of json file is a time key called tstamp. How can I store and retrieve data based on tstamp attribute?? My code:

```
// Backbone model Creation for highlight
var HighlightModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        tstamp: "1234",
        att: "",

    },

    initialize: function () {

    }

});

//Backbone model initialization
highlight = new HighlightModel();

var HighlightList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: HighlightModel,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("highlightList"),
    url: 'data.json'

});

var HighlightView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: "#highlights",
    template: _.template($('#highlightTemplate').html()),
    render: function (eventName) {

        _.each(this.model.models, function (highlight) {
            var highlightTemplate = this.template(highlight.toJSON());

            //push data to obj for highlight script
            mp = highlight.toJSON();
            // Add data to DOM element
            $(this.el).html(highlightTemplate);
        }, this);

        return this; // .remove(); to stop displaying    
    }

});

var highlights = new HighlightList([highlight]);
var highlightsView = new HighlightView({
    model: highlights
});


// Fetching data from server every n seconds
setInterval(function () {

    highlights.fetch({
        reset: true
    });

   highlight.add(sentiments);
highlights.save();
}, htCycle); // Time in milliseconds

highlights.bind('reset', function () {

    highlightsView.render();
    console.log('render');

});
```

EDIT:

I change my code a little bit, now i have at local storage just store the default model {"tstamp":"1234","att":"","id":"4fb1b437-0e37-8eb7-ed3c-cbd9d0dcff98"}. I want to store the fetched data from server to localstorage.

Comment: The localStorage adapter replaced the sync functionally so that it saves to localStorage. IF you need to save both locally and to the server  you might want to look at the following two projects:  [backbone.offline](https://github.com/ask11/backbone-offline) and [backbone.dualStorage](https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage).

Comment: I am a little bit confused, I ve just want to fetch data from server which is actually what I do, and store that data to localstore.

Comment: The problem is that the localStorage adapter replaces the `fetch` so that it instead fetches from localStorage. You need to either manually *fetch* (that is make a standard ajax request) you data from your server and add it to your collection or override the sync method yourself (which is essentially what those two projects I linked to do, however i haven't used either myself).

Comment: I wrote a plugin called [backbone.hoard](https://github.com/cmaher/backbone.hoard) to handle this problem (among others).